# Check if first 10 chars are sorted per line

Tags: bash, sorting

I want to check if the first column (10 chars) is sorted for lines that looks like this:

```
   ,K4a-:v  000000000000000000000000001B8132  5555EEEE888899994444FFFF1111CCCCEEEE1111EEEE6666FFFF
   =2G^9{-  000000000000000000000000000809EE  5555DDDD1111CCCC9999BBBB0000BBBBCCCCFFFFCCCC44443333
```

I've tried with `cut -b 1-10 file |  sort -i -c || echo -n "not " ; echo "sorted"` but it says it's not sorted, even though it is. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The 3 whitespaces in front are intentional

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works for me.

Comment: When I run it I get `sort: -:2: disorder:    =2G^9{-
not sorted`

Comment: I get `sorted`. For debugging, I suggest that you pipe your output of `cut` into `xxd`, so that we can see the hexadecimal content. Perhaps you have a tab character instead of a space, or something along that line.

Comment: What locale are you using? Your locale may specify that `,` does not precede `=`.

Comment: How can I check what I'm using @chepner ?

Comment: Output of `xxd` is  `00000000: 2020 202c 4b34 612d 3a76 0a20 2020 3d32     ,K4a-:v.   =2`
`00000010: 475e 397b 2d0a                           G^9{-.`

Comment: Run the `locale` command; the most relevant setting would probably be `LC_COLLATE`, but unless you have an odd set-up, all reported environment variables (aside from perhaps `LC_ALL`) should have the same value.

Comment: Ahh I have a few abnormalities, since I'm from Denmark there is a mix of `en_DK.UTF-8` and  `en_US.UTF-8`. The collate is `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: Try `LC_COLLATE=C` for sorting based on ASCII values

Comment: @glennjackman : Do you by chance know, where I can find the sort order for en_US.UTF-8? I googled and found plenty of statements, that the sort order (not surprisingly) depends on the _collate_ setting, but I found not a single site which actually would tell me what the sort order for a certain COLLATE value would be.

Comment: Not really, but start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository

Answer (score 0):

Setting `LC_COLLATE=C` and restarting worked

Comment: A restart shouldn't be necessary. The important point is to have this variable set in the environment of the process which does the sorting. Therefore a simple `LC_COLLATE=C sort -i -c` would have been sufficient for debugging the issue.